# separate alphabet combination into columns with single alphabet value python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

using python 3.8, pandas 1.1.4

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
id             combination  
1      'A23B14C02R01D05E03F07G07H01I00J02K11L30'
2      'A11B14C02R01D05E03F07G07H01I00J02K11L30'
3      'A30B14C02R01D05E03F07G07H01I00J02K11L30'
...
```

What I want to do is separate combination column into multiple columns that consist one alphabet only.

Desired output should look like this:

```
id    A     B   C   R    D   E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L
1    23    14   02  01   05  03  07   07   01   00   02    11  30
2    11    14   02  01   05  03  07   07   01   00   02    11  30
3    30    14   02  01   05  03  07   07   01   00   02    11  30
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try with `findall` then `explode` and `crosstab` for pivot

```
s = df.combination.str.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)').explode()
df = df.join(pd.crosstab(index=s.index,columns=s.str[0],values=s.str[1],aggfunc='first'))
df
   id                              combination   A   B   C  ...   I   J   K   L   R
0   1  A23B14C02R01D05E03F07G07H01I00J02K11L30  23  14  02  ...  00  02  11  30  01
1   2  A11B14C02R01D05E03F07G07H01I00J02K11L30  11  14  02  ...  00  02  11  30  01
2   3  A30B14C02R01D05E03F07G07H01I00J02K11L30  30  14  02  ...  00  02  11  30  01
[3 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: My combinations should contain alphabets A-L and R, how could I do that? `df.combination.str.findall('([a-lA-L or rR]+)(\d+)').explode()`

Comment: `str.findall('([A-L|R]+)(\d+)')` this seems to do the job!

Comment: @Ambleu great you find it ~

Comment: Hey @BENY your method works great until `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.02 GiB for an array with shape (2, 68324178) and data type object` happened. Is there more memory efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

We can try `extractall` and pivot:

```
df[['id']].join(df.combination.str.extractall('(\D+)(\d*)')
   .set_index(0, append=True)
   .reset_index('match',drop=True)
   [1].unstack(0)
)
```

Output:

```
   id   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   R
0   1  23  14  02  05  03  07  07  01  00  02  11  30  01
1   2  11  14  02  05  03  07  07  01  00  02  11  30  01
2   3  30  14  02  05  03  07  07  01  00  02  11  30  01
```